# Derive public key from xpub?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets

I woud like to obtain an extended public key of a derivation path (m/84'/0'/0').
I'm using btclib, and I have the xpub of the root account.

When I try to use `bip32.derive("xpub...","m/84'/0'/0'")`

I get `btclib.exceptions.BTClibValueError: invalid hardened derivation from public key`

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review [BIP32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki):

> The fact that they are equivalent is what makes non-hardened keys
> useful (one can derive child public keys of a given parent key without
> knowing any private key), and also what distinguishes them from
> hardened keys. The reason for not always using non-hardened keys
> (which are more useful) is security; see further for more information.

That little apostrophe `'` means that branch of the key derivation tree is "hardened" -- and THAT means that you must have the private key to derive its child keys.

So if you have the PRIVATE key for `m/84'/0'/0'` you can generate child keys for example `m/84'/0'/0'/0` or `m/84'/0'/0'/0'` (these are two different keys, one is hardened the other is not).

If you were to derive the non-hardened key at `m/84'/0'/0'/0` then you could use an xpub FROM THIS KEY (not any of the parent keys) to derive public child keys, without any private keys. Examples would be `m/84'/0'/0'/0/0` and `m/84'/0'/0'/0/1`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Just another precision: If I have ONLY the xpub key of the top account (the xpub key than can be exported from a Ledger wallet for instance),  it is not possible to get the xpub key at m/84'/0'/0' with btclib derive function so. But can I get the xpub key at  m/84'/0'/0'/0 (or m/84'/0'/0'/1) ?

Comment: See https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0084.mediawiki#public-key-derivation The xpub you get from a Ledger is (I'm pretty sure) at the account level. Meaning from there you can derive change and receive addresses like `m/84'/0'/0'/0/0`. What you should try with your library is to take the xpub and just derive the last two levels: `xpub/0/0`

Comment: More precisely bip32.derive("xpub...","/0") for receive addresses